# Create generic containers that dynamically expand for text

Tags: boxes, code, syntax, rounded-corners

**Problem:**

I am trying to create color containers that can hold text that vary in size. What I have not been able to figure is what method you should use in order to achieve this.

**Example 1:**

[image]

**Example 2:**

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

Be able to create a figure that allows text containers to dynamically expand based on text size. All examples follow the same setup: 3 boxes on top, 1 box in the middle, and one box at the bottom.

I would appreciate if someone could give pointers how/where to begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using tikz:

The following simple macro typesets a colored box with some text:

```
\newcommand{\mycolorbox}[2][gray]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(n.base)] \node[rounded corners,%
                                   white,% Font color
                                   node font=\sffamily,% Sans serif font
                                   fill=#1,% Fill box with optional argument color
                                   inner xsep=5pt% Horizontal padding
                                  ](n){\mathstrut#2};%
}
```

Here is an example of use:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mycolorbox}[2][gray]{\tikz[baseline=(n.base)] \node[rounded corners,white,node font=\sffamily,fill=#1,inner xsep=5pt](n){\mathstrut#2};}
\begin{document}
\mycolorbox[magenta]{while} \mycolorbox[cyan]{(condition)} \mycolorbox{\textbraceleft}\\
    \hspace*{15pt}\mycolorbox[orange]{Code}\\
\mycolorbox{\textbraceright}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendering]

Comment: Thank you kindly! But I have two questions 1) how do you increase the space above and under the orange box? 2) how do you increase the size of the entire colorbox?

Comment: You can increase the interline space, depending on how you use the boxes. To change the size of the boxes, you can set the `inner xsep` and `inner ysep` parameters in the `\node` call (they increase _padding_, if you are familiar with _css_).